# App Update on playstore does reflect on all android Devices

Tags: android

When i update my android app on play store, then updated app does not reflect on some devices,
now iam using android sdk ,app update callback methods ,through which also i am getting the same problem,
In my app 800-900 active user at a time. I even cant told to everyone that "please clear cache and see the updates" which will be very frustating for the users,
SO can someone help me in this.

try:
app upload on playstore

expect:
it should be visible to all users not for some few.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue... Did you solve it?